# How can you stop repeating yourself when writing slightly different for loops?

Tags: c#

I have these selections and iterations statements. I feel like that I am doing something wrong; I feel like repeating myself too much and that some of it could really be optimized.

**Question**: how can you optimize multiple, slightly different, for loops into something that is "better"?

Here is the code (note that the surrounding function applies to a timer that "ticks" every 0,5 sec):

```
step = 0; //step is a member variable of the surrounding class

timer1_tick(Object obj, EventArg arg)
{
    if (step == 0)
    {
        foreach (HtmlElement elem in browser.Document.GetElementsByTag("a"))
        {
            if (elem.InnerText == "hey")
            {
                elem.InnerText = "blabla";
                break;
            }
        }

        foreach (HtmlElement elem in browser.Document.GetElementsByTag("button"))
        {
            if (elem.InnerText == "clickMe")
            {
                step = 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        return;
    }
    else if (step == 1)
    {
        foreach (HtmlElement elem in browser.Document.GetElementsByTag("div"))
        {
            if (elem.GetAttribute("name") == "something")
            {
                elem.Destroy;
                break;
            }

            if (elem.GetAttribute("name") == "notme")
            {
                elem.Destroy;
                break;
            }

            if (elem.GetAttribute("name") == "notyou")
            {
                elem.Destroy;
                break;
            }

            if (elem.GetAttribute("name") == "notthat")
            {
                elem.Destroy;
                break;
            }

            if (elem.GetAttribute("name") == "theone")
            {
                elem.Destroy;
                break;
            }
        }

        step = 2;
        return;
    }
    else if (step == 2)
    {
        foreach (HtmlElement elem in browser.Document.GetElementsByTag("div"))
        {
            if (elem.InnerHtml == "ClickMeNow")
            {
                elem.InnerHtml = "/Done";
                step = 3;
                break;
            }
        }

        foreach (HtmlElement elem in browser.Document.GetElementsByTag("a"))
        {
            if (elem.InnerHtml == "linkit")
            {
                elem.getAttribute("href") = "www.google.com";
                step = 3;
                break;
            }
        }

        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format the code, its not readable like this

Comment: @EpicKip how? I just wrote it directly and the output was this. Btw., I am new here :)

Comment: @sdsadasdasd You never indent your code? You might want to make a habit of it.

Comment: Also, it could theoretically be any code where the situation is that you have a ton of slightly different for loops and you feel like something is wrong...

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Sometimes when you copy paste your code from your IDE into the code snippet thingy here it gets this terrible format, but you have to go manual trough it and apply some formatting love.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Well, is usually happens automatically when I program in different IDEs.. Just discovered that Tim has fixed it for me, thanks man!

Comment: @sdsadasdasd `and you feel like something is wrong` is quite subjective. And as Manfred said, you can make it readable by indenting code ^^

Comment: First refactoring should be to extract methods with meaningful names for every step. The step itself should be an `enum`(with meaningful name) instead of an `int`.

Comment: You can make it a bit smaller by doing the filtering in the foreach (so no if's) eg.: `foreach(HtmlElement elem in browser.Document.GetElementsByTag("a").Where(a => a.InnerText == "Hey"))`

Comment: `ternary expressions` can probably save you lots of redundant lines here.

Comment: @EpicKip, the code was indented in my IDE... And regarding that statement - I know, but it is rather based on some principles that I know, which kinda makes it less subjective, right.. Thanks for your time guys

Comment: you could combine the if's with ors and make 1 if and not repeat the elem.Destory;break;

Comment: Your step 1 could be improved by doing `if (MyListOfNames.Contains(elem.GetAttribute("name"))) {elem.Destroy()}`. At the end of the day though this question is too broad. It might be worth seeing if this question would be better received at codereview.stackexchange.com (I've no idea if it would be since I don't hang out there). Here though it is too broad really since there are so many different possibilities of what you might consider wrong with this code and what you might do to improve it (as demonstrated by the fact you have several totally different suggestions here in comments).

Comment: Also the foreachs don't look that similar to me. One sets the inner text of elements, one of them destroys elements, one of them sets the inner html... The only thing they seem to have in common is that they are all foreach loops. Is it just the fetching of the thing you loop over that you are hoping to reduce redundancy for? If so then replacing `browser.Document.GetElementsByTag("div")` with `MyGetElements("div")` might make things more readable.

Comment: @sdsadasdasd `and you feel like something is wrong` isn't based on any principles if you don't name them :)

Comment: @Chris Thanks Chris!! It helped.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ to eliminate all these loops.
Note that instead of breaking out of the loop you can simply use `FirstOrDefault`:

For instance, the first loop:

```
    foreach (HtmlElement elem in browser.Document.GetElementsByTag("a"))
    {
        if (elem.InnerText == "hey")
        {
            elem.InnerText = "blabla";
            break;
        }
    }
```

can be replaced with:

```
var elem = browser.Document.GetElementsByTag("a").FirstOrDefault(e => e.InnerText == "hey");
if(elem != null)
{
    elem.InnerText = "blabla";
}
```

Similarly, you can use LINQ to replace the other loops as well:

```
foreach (HtmlElement elem in browser.Document.GetElementsByTag("button"))
{
    if (elem.InnerText == "clickMe")
    {
        step = 1;
        break;
    }
}
```

can be replaced by:

```
var elem = browser.Document.GetElementsByTag("button").FirstOrDefault(e => e.InnerText == "clickMe");
if(elem != null)
{
    step = 1;
}
```

This massive loop:

```
foreach (HtmlElement elem in browser.Document.GetElementsByTag("div"))
{
    if (elem.GetAttribute("name") == "something")
    {
        elem.Destroy;
        break;
    }
    if (elem.GetAttribute("name") == "notme")
    {
        elem.Destroy;
        break;
    }
    if (elem.GetAttribute("name") == "notyou")
    {
        elem.Destroy;
        break;
    }
    if (elem.GetAttribute("name") == "notthat")
    {
        elem.Destroy;
        break;
    }
    if (elem.GetAttribute("name") == "theone")
    {
        elem.Destroy;
        break;
    }
}
```

can be replaced by:

```
var names = new string[] {"something", "notme", "notyou", "notthat", "theone"};
browser.Document.GetElementsByTag("div").FirstOrDefault(e => names.Contains(e.GetAttribute("name"))?.Destroy;
```

Note I've used the Contains method of the string array instead of all the conditions in your code.

And so on.

Also, I would take Tim's advice and change the `step 1`, `step 2` etc' to different methods with meaningful names.

Comment: Your final statement is incorrect, you cannot write to the conditional access expression returned by the null conditional operator - it can only be used for reading or querying

Comment: @LordWilmore I'm not sure what statement you are referring to because I was editing the answer when you posted your comment. Can you be more specific?

Comment: The comment regarding null conditional operators in C#6

Answer (score 1):

I would do a few things differently with this code:

### Break up the method

Your `timer1_tick` method does a lot of things. Normally i'm not a fan of arbitrarily breaking up code to small methods, but I think it's suiting here. Moreover, instead of the outer `if... else if...` sturucture, a switch would be more appropriate.

So the general structure of your code would look something like this:

```
public void FirstStep()
{
    //...
}

public void SecondStep()
{
    //...
}

public void ThirdStep()
{
    //...
}

public void timer1_tick()
{
    switch(step)
    {
        case 1:
            FirstStep();
            break;
        case 2:
            SecondStep();
            break;
        case 1:
            ThirdStep();
            break;
    }
}
```

### Improve the foreach

Next, Let's tackle the for each loops. In the first and third steps, your structure is always the same:

```
foreach (HtmlElement elem in browser.Document.GetElementsByTag("<<Selector>>"))
{
    if (elem.InnerText == "<<Selector>>")
    {
        // Do logic...
    }
}
```

So let's extract that to a different method, and use this for the foreach call.

```
public IEnumerable<HtmlElement> GetElementByTagAndContent(string tag, string content)
{
    foreach (HtmlElement elem in browser.Document.GetElementsByTag(tag))
    {
        if (elem.InnerText == content)
            yield return elem
    }
}
```

and the foreach loops would look like this:

```
foreach(var elem in GetElementByTagAndContent("a", "hey))
{
    // Do Logic...
}
```

### Refactor the Second step

Finally, in the second step, you're doing a bunch of `if`s that only check the name of the element. Also, they all do the same action. A `switch` statement is classic here.

```
switch (elem.GetAttribute("name"))
{
    case "A":
    case "B":        
    case "C":
    case "D":
        elem.Destroy();
        break;
}
```

### Final Product

After all those, your code should look more like this:

```
public void FirstStep()
{
    foreach (HtmlElement elem in GetElementByTagAndContent("a", "hey"))
    {
        elem.InnerText = "blabla";
    }

    foreach (HtmlElement elem in GetElementByTagAndContent("button", "clickMe"))
    {
        step = 1;
    }
}

public void SecondStep()
{
    switch (elem.GetAttribute("name"))
    {
        case "A":
        case "B":        
        case "C":
        case "D":
            elem.Destroy();
            break;
    }

    step = 2;
}

public void ThirdStep()
{
    foreach (HtmlElement elem in GetElementByTagAndContent("div", "ClickMeNow"))
    {
        elem.InnerHtml = "/Done";
        step = 3;
    }

    foreach (HtmlElement elem in GetElementByTagAndContent("a", "linkit"))
    {
        elem.getAttribute("href") = "www.google.com";
        step = 3;
    }
}

public void timer1_tick()
{
    switch(step)
    {
        case 1:
            FirstStep();
            break;
         case 2:
            SecondStep();
            break;
        case 1:
            ThirdStep();
            break;
    }
}

public IEnumerable<HtmlElement> GetElementByTagAndContent(string tag, string content)
{
    foreach (HtmlElement elem in browser.Document.GetElementsByTag(tag))
    {
        if (elem.InnerText == content)
            yield return elem
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Exactly. I was going to start typing an answer over lunch but this pretty much covers it - breaking up the method into it's key discrete elements is the key